# Ease-in text after text element is created and given class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Okay, so I'm trying to get this thing to work.
Basically, when I load (*just to test for now, will use a button in the future*) the page, I want it to add a 'p' element to an existing node (div1).  Then I want to add a class to that 'p' element I just created (load).  Basically, my goal is to "ease-in" the text I just created using the style class provided (load).  Problem is, it's not "easing in", it's just instantly showing up.  I am stuck, what can I do?

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <style>
    #div1 p {
        opacity: 0;
        margin-top: 25px;
        font-size: 21px;
        text-align: center;
        -webkit-transition: opacity 2s ease-in;
        -moz-transition: opacity 2s ease-in;
        -o-transition: opacity 2s ease-in;
        -ms-transition: opacity 2s ease-in;
        transition: opacity 2s ease-in;
    }
    #div1 p.load {
        opacity: 1;
    }
    </style>

    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body onload="js()">
    <div id="div1">
    </div>
    </body>

    <script>
    function js(){
        // Construct new p element with text
        var newElem = document.createElement("p");
        var newElemText = document.createTextNode("Evan is the man!");
        newElem.appendChild(newElemText);

        // Add the p element to existing node, div1
        var element = document.getElementById("div1");
        element.appendChild(newElem);

        // Add class to new p element inside node div1
        $($("#div1 p")).addClass("load");
    }
    </script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code has a few errors :

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            #div1 p {
                opacity: 0;
                margin-top: 25px;
                font-size: 21px;
                text-align: center;
                -webkit-transition: opacity 2s ease-in;
                -moz-transition: opacity 2s ease-in;
                -o-transition: opacity 2s ease-in;
                -ms-transition: opacity 2s ease-in;
                transition: opacity 2s ease-in;
            }
            #div1 p.load {
                opacity: 1;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body onload="js()">
        <div id="div1">
        </div>
    </body>
    <script>
        function js(){
            // Construct new p element with text
            var newElem = document.createElement("p");
            var newElemText = document.createTextNode("Evan is the man!");
            newElem.appendChild(newElemText);

            // Add the p element to existing node, div1
            var element = document.getElementById("div1");
            element.appendChild(newElem);
            // Add class to new p element inside node div1
            setTimeout(function(){
               newElem.className += " load";
            },0);
        }
    </script>
</html>
```

- Your first `<style>` must be in the `<head>` tag.
- `$($("#div1 p"))`, wrap it only once.
- Put your `.addClass` inside a `setTimeout`.
- Consider removing your dependency to jQuery by using `newElem.className += " load";` instead of `$("#div1 p").addClass("load")`.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/47o3Lj7u/2/).

Comment: If he's using jquery then having to invoke the animation with javascript anyway why not just use $('#div1 p').fadeIn(2000); or .animate if you want an easing effect

Comment: Efficiency. And that's what he was trying to do. Using CSS3 to make a transition.

Comment: setTimeout isnt efficient.

Comment: Why are you thinking this?

Comment: in this sense, it seems more like hack plus youre using javascript to invoke the animation anyway why not just use a library already loaded.  there won't be any measurable performance differences in this scenerio.

Comment: He's barely using jQuery, he doesn't need it... to choose, it's better to remove jQuery than using it to animate.

Answer (score -1):

As far as I know you need to use javascript to fade elements on page load, css3 transitions are more for dom events after the page is loaded.  Maybe try @keyframes but then you will probably run into legacy browser issues.

Comment: His solution is good. There is only a few little typos easy to miss.